# Efficiently wait for a flag state change without blocking resources?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, performance

Thread to wait **infinitely** in a loop until a **flag state** change, then call function.

**pseudo code illustration:**

```
while (true)
{
    while (!flag)
    {
            sleep(1);
    }
    clean_upfunction();
}
```

**Currently**:

- Using the multithreaded versions of the [**C run-time libraries only**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.80).aspx)

**No:**

- MFC

**Question:**

- Is there a more efficient way of implementing the above
- A waitForStateChange() - similar to above - in the threading library

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Windows (which you have this tagged for), you want to look at [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx). Use a Windows Event (with CreateEvent), then wait on it; the other thread should call SetEvent. All native Windows, no MFC or anything else required.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks - just what am looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're not on Windows, and are instead on a POSIXish box, `pthread_cond_wait` is the best match:

```
/* signaler */
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    flag = true;
    pthread_cond_signal(cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

/* waiter */
    pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
    do {
        pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
    } while (!flag);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
```

The classic self-pipe trick is easier and cooler though :)  Works on systems without `pthreads` too.

```
/* setup */
    int pipefd[2];
    if (pipe(pipefd) < 0) {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(-1);
    }

/* signaler */
    char byte = 0;
    write(pipefd[0], &byte, 1);  // omitting error handling for brevity

/* waiter */
    char byte;
    read(pipefd[1], &byte, 1);  // omitting error handling for brevity
```

The waiter will block on the `read` (you don't set `O_NONBLOCK`) until interrupted (which is why you should have error handling) or the signaler writes a byte.

Comment: There's pthread_cond_timedwait.  For the self-pipe method... you can use alarm() if you're forking, but that doesn't work too well with a threaded program.

Comment: By the way, I think it might be backwards above for pipefd... `write(pipefd[1], &byte, 1); and read(pipefd[0], &byte, 1);` were the ones that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at condition_variable in Boost.Thread.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref

It is portable, easier to use than the platform-specific options. Moreover, IIUC, the upcoming C++0x std::condition_variable was modeled after it.